# How to set sqlite3 default "pragma secure_delete=true" without compile on windows 10 home

Tags: windows, cmd, sqlite, default, pragma

I have sqlite3 version 3.15.2 on a Windows 10 home laptop. What I need/want is the same thing, but with the pragma secure_delete set to true so it applies to every database I use, but I can't compile sqlite3. Secure_delete just writes 0s into the database memory when a tuple is deleted. Is there some way I can set some environment variable or other trick to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to enable this setting are to set the [SQLITE_SECURE_DELETE compilation option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#secure_delete), or to execute the [secure_delete PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_secure_delete) for each new database connection.

So what you want is not possible.